# Deploying AWS Load Balancer Controller on EKS with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

Trying to deploy [aws-load-balancer-controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/) on Kubernetes.

I have the following TF code:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "ingress" {
  metadata {
    name      = "alb-ingress-controller"
    namespace = "kube-system"
    labels = {
      app.kubernetes.io/name = "alb-ingress-controller" 
      app.kubernetes.io/version = "v2.2.3"
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by = "terraform"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app.kubernetes.io/name = "alb-ingress-controller" 
      }
    }

    strategy {
      type = "Recreate"
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
                app.kubernetes.io/name = "alb-ingress-controller" 
                app.kubernetes.io/version = "v2.2.3"
        }
      }

      spec {
        dns_policy                       = "ClusterFirst"
        restart_policy                   = "Always"
        service_account_name             = kubernetes_service_account.ingress.metadata[0].name
        termination_grace_period_seconds = 60

        container {
          name              = "alb-ingress-controller"
          image             = "docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v2.2.3"
          image_pull_policy = "Always"

          args = [
            "--ingress-class=alb",
            "--cluster-name=${local.k8s[var.env].esk_cluster_name}",
            "--aws-vpc-id=${local.k8s[var.env].cluster_vpc}",
            "--aws-region=${local.k8s[var.env].region}"
          ]
          volume_mount {
            mount_path = "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
            name       = kubernetes_service_account.ingress.default_secret_name
            read_only  = true
          }
        }
        volume {
          name = kubernetes_service_account.ingress.default_secret_name

          secret {
            secret_name = kubernetes_service_account.ingress.default_secret_name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  depends_on = [kubernetes_cluster_role_binding.ingress]
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress" "app" {
  metadata {
    name      = "owncloud-lb"
    namespace = "fargate-node"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class"           = "alb"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme"      = "internet-facing"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type" = "ip"
    }
    labels = {
      "app" = "owncloud"
    }
  }

  spec {
    backend {
      service_name = "owncloud-service"
      service_port = 80
    }
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          path = "/"
          backend {
            service_name = "owncloud-service"
            service_port = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  depends_on = [kubernetes_service.app]
}
```

This works up to version `1.9` as required. As soon as I upgrade to version `2.2.3` the pod fails to update and on the pod get the following error:`{"level":"error","ts":1629207071.4385357,"logger":"setup","msg":"unable to create controller","controller":"TargetGroupBinding","error":"no matches for kind \"TargetGroupBinding\" in version \"elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1\""}`

I have read the update the doc and have amended the IAM policy as they state but they also mention:

> updating the TargetGroupBinding CRDs

And that where I am not sure how to do that using terraform

If I try to do deploy on a new cluster (e.g not an upgrade from 1.9 I get the same error) I get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your Terraform code, you apply an `Deployment` and an `Ingress` resource, but you must also add the `CustomResourceDefinitions` for the `TargetGroupBinding` custom resource.

This is described under "Add Controller to Cluster" in the [Load Balancer Controller installation documentation](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/deploy/installation/) - with examples for Helm and Kubernetes Yaml provided.

Terraform has [beta support for applying CRDs](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/beta-support-for-crds-in-the-terraform-provider-for-kubernetes) including an [example of deploying CustomResourceDefinition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest#example-create-a-kubernetes-custom-resource-definition).

Comment: okay thanks for that ... just wondering if you have or know of any online resource you recommend on how you could run helm commands using terraform ?

Comment: @alexis I updated my answer with Terraform beta support for CRDs including a link to an example for applying CustomResourceDefinitions.

Comment: thank you very much. I am sure this enough for me to figure it out and take it from here. Thanks again for your time